# Como converter uma string para Data com o nome do mês em português

Tags: python, pandas, data

Tenho um df na qual a primeira coluna data (`13-mai-2019`) está como *string* e eu quero convertê-la para `13-Maio-2019` ou `13-5-2019`.

Eu usei o seguinte código:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%B-%Y')
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: time data '13-mai-2019' does not match format '%d-%B-%Y'

Comment: `'13-mai-2019'` não está dentro do formato esperado, mas `'13-May-2019'` está. Sua aplicação está devidamente configurada com a localização correta?

Comment: eu estou tirando a informaçao dum ficheiro excel, na qual gravei como csv.

Comment: Mas isso não responde sobre a configuração da localização. Se possui uma data em português, você configurou o Python para trabalhar com essa localização?

Comment: Desculpa, eu estou me a iniciar no pandas, tenho ainda alguma dificuldade, o locale parece estar em Portugues, posso saber como ver?

Answer (score 6):

Há um erro e um potencial problema na sua aplicação.

O erro é que a formatação definida por `%B` espera o **nome completo do mês**, enquanto no valor a ser tratado você possui apenas o nome reduzido. Ou seja, o `%B` você usaria apenas se possuísse a data como `'13-maio-2019'`. Como tem o nome reduzido, precisa utilizar `%b`, em minúsculo.

O potencial problema é que você possui a data em português e, por padrão, o Python é localizado para trabalhar com os valores em inglês. Para corrigir a localização precisará utilizar o módulo `locale`:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')
```

E, a partir disso, a sua data será tratada corretamente:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('13-Mai-2019', '%d-%b-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 13, 0, 0)
```

Para verificar qual é a localização atual, basta verificar o valor retornado por `locale.getlocale()`. Vale lembrar que o módulo `locale` utilizará bibliotecas em C para fazer esse gerenciamento, que dependem diretamente das configurações do seu sistema operacional. Para verificar quais são os valores possíveis para o seu SO atualmente basta executar o comando `locale -a` no terminal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: **nota**, caso o seu ambiente seja windows pode obter a localização atual dentro do prompt do PowerShell digitando [`[System.Globalization.Cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8)