# Converter string em data

Tags: python, datetime

Possuo um data frame cuja coluna que me mostra a data tem o formato `'nov/19'` e é um object, preciso convertê-la para o formato de data.

Sei que na documentação do `datetime` é dito que ele lê mês de 1 à 12, porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma deu conseguir fazer a conversão para data e a data continuar sendo exibida como 'nov/19'.

O código que tentei fazer até o momento:

```
str_date = 'nov/19'

date = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%m/%Y').date()
```

Porém, recebo o erro:

> ```
> ValueError: time data 'nov/19' does not match format '%m/%Y'
> ```

Comment: Você quer novembro-2019 como saída?

Comment: Você quer converter a string nov/19 para uma data válida e continuar exibindo a mesma como nov/19?

Comment: na verdade eu acabei descobrindo meu erro ao conhecer as outras referencias da strftime pois o %m é para mês em número e %Y é para ano no formato YYYY, já consegui descobrir quais as referências apropriadas para meu caso, obrigada mesmo assim.

Comment: Então posta a sua solução para caso alguém tenha a dúvida e encerrar a a pergunta flw

Answer (score 2):

Se você consultar os [formatos descritos na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), verá que para o nome do mês abreviado deve ser usado `%b`, e para o ano com 2 dígitos, usa-se `%y`.

Mas ainda tem outro detalhe: quando o ano tem 2 dígitos, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html), valores entre 0 e 68 são mapeados para os anos 2000 a 2068, e valores entre 69 e 99 são mapeados para os anos 1969 e 1999.

Não ficou claro com quais valores você quer trabalhar e quais datas quer gerar, mas **caso queira** mudar esta regra, uma alternativa seria:

```
from datetime import datetime

def year_2to4_digit(two_digit_year, pivotyear = 1950):
    century = (pivotyear // 100) * 100
    if century + two_digit_year > pivotyear:
        return century + two_digit_year
    return century + 100 + two_digit_year

str_date = 'nov/19'
date = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%b/%y').date()
date = date.replace(year = year_2to4_digit(date.year % 100))
```

Ou seja, valores entre 51 e 99 seriam convertidos para os anos entre 1951 e 1999. Os demais valores (0 a 50) estariam entre 2000 e 2050. Se quiser outra "data de corte", basta mudar o parâmetro `pivotyear` na função `year_2to4_digit`. No seu caso específico ("19"), a API já mapeia para 2019, que parece ser o desejado. De qualquer forma, deixo a opção registrada, já que anos com 2 dígitos podem ter esse problema e é importante saber contorná-lo.

---

Outro detalhe é que para o nome do mês abreviado, por *default* considera-se que estará em inglês. Ou seja, fevereiro será "feb", e se tentar fazer *parsing* da versão em português, ou seja, "fev", dará erro:

```
str_date = 'fev/19'
date = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%b/%y').date() # ValueError
```

No seu caso não está claro qual o idioma usado, já que tanto em inglês quanto em português a abreviação de novembro é "nov".

Mas se a ideia é poder fazer *parsing* de datas em português, você pode usar o [módulo `locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html):

```
import locale
# setar locale para português
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')

str_date = 'fev/19'
date = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%b/%y').date()
```

Lembrando que neste caso o respectivo *locale* deve estar instalado no sistema, [conforme explicado nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385217/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Resposta correta:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%b/%y').date().strftime('%b-%y')
```

Comment: segue link de referencias para formatos diferentes de data: https://strftime.org/