# Selecionar dados de acordo com um horário específico

Tags: python, python-3.x, data, datetime

Estou fazendo um programa em que, dado o dia da semana, as horas e os minutos atuais, ele responde com todos os "Médicos" disponíveis naquele horário.

Cada médico possui um período de atendimento. Por exemplo:

- Carlos atende às segundas-feiras das 10:00 até às 12:00, e às quintas-feiras das 15:00 até as 16:30.
- Juliana atende às segundas-feiras das 10:00 até às 11:30, e às sextas-feiras das 15:00 até as 16:00.

Caso alguém rode o programa às 11:00 da segunda-feira, o programa deve printar que o Carlos e a Juliana estão disponíveis. Caso rode à quarta-feira às 15:00, o programa deve avisar que não há ninguém disponível. E por fim, caso rode na quinta-feira às 15:00, deve retornar que o Carlos está disponível.

Estou fazendo isso utilizando Python 3. Minha lógica é uma sequência de `if` e `else` com os respectivos horários, mas tenho certeza absoluta que é uma maneira bem burra de resolver esse problema.

```
   from datetime import datetime
   from datetime import date
   
 async def responder(ctx):
    hoje = date.today()
    now = datetime.now()
    
    diaDaSemana = date.today()
    hora = now.hour
    minuto = now.minute
    
    if(diaDaSemana == 0):
        resposta = segundaFeira(hora, minuto)
    
    
    response = random.choice(brooklyn_99_quotes)
    await ctx.send(response)

def segundaFeira(hora, minuto):
    str = "Disponiveis: "
    if hora => 10 and hora <= 12:
        str += "Carlos"
    return str
```

Com certeza há uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso. Gostaria de saber qual é este jeito, posso usar qualquer biblioteca do python.

Comment: sugiro dar uma olhada na definição de dicionário, poderia se fazer cada dia da semana com uma lista com cada profissional disponível e seus respectivos horários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é guardar os horários disponíveis e os respectivos médicos em um dicionário. Uma sugestão é ter esta estrutura:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

# dias da semana: 0 - segunda, 1 - terça, etc
horarios = {
    'Carlos': {
        0: (time(10, 0), time(12, 0)), # segunda, das 10h às 12h
        3: (time(15, 0), time(16, 30)) # quinta, das 15h às 16:30
    },
    'Juliana': {
        0: (time(10, 0), time(11, 30)), # segunda, das 10h às 11:30
        5: (time(15, 0), time(16, 0)) # sexta, das 15h às 16h
    }
}
```

Ou seja, para cada nome, eu tenho um outro dicionário contendo os dias da semana (usando os valores 0 para segunda, 1 para terça, e assim por diante). Fiz assim para ficar compatível com os [valores retornados por `datetime.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday).

E para cada dia da semana, eu crio uma tupla com o horário inicial e final. Com isso, basta percorrer a estrutura e ver se o horário se encaixa em uma delas:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

# dias da semana: 0 - segunda, 1 - terça, etc
horarios = {
    'Carlos': {
        0: (time(10, 0), time(12, 0)), # segunda, das 10h às 12h
        3: (time(15, 0), time(16, 30)) # quinta, das 15h às 16:30
    },
    'Juliana': {
        0: (time(10, 0), time(11, 30)), # segunda, das 10h às 11:30
        5: (time(15, 0), time(16, 0)) # sexta, das 15h às 16h
    }
}

# data e hora atual
hoje = datetime.now()
dia_da_semana = hoje.weekday() # obter o dia da semana
horario = hoje.time() # pegar somente o horário

# imprime a data atual
print(f'Hoje é {hoje:%A, %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S}')
encontrado = False
for nome, disponibilidade in horarios.items(): # para cada médico
    if dia_da_semana in disponibilidade: # se atende no dia da semana
        inicio, fim = disponibilidade[dia_da_semana]
        if inicio <= horario <= fim: # verifica se horário está entre o início e fim
            print(f'{nome} está disponível das {inicio:%H:%M} às {fim:%H:%M}')
            encontrado = True

if not encontrado:
    print('Não há médicos disponíveis')
```

---

O detalhe é que ao imprimir o dia da semana, por *default* é mostrado o nome em inglês. Para imprimir em português, você precisa usar o [módulo `locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html):

```
import locale
# setar locale para português
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')

# restante do programa é igual
```

Lembrando que neste caso o respectivo *locale* deve estar instalado no sistema, [conforme explicado nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385217/112052).

E usei [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) para imprimir a data e os horários. Mas se estiver usando uma versão do Python anterior à 3.6 uma alternativa é usar [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) juntamente com [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). Basta trocar os `print`'s por:

```
print('Hoje é {}'.format(hoje.strftime('%A, %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')))

print('{} está disponível das {} às {}'.format(nome, inicio.strftime('%H:%M'), fim.strftime('%H:%M')))
```

---

Reparei que você está montando uma string com os nomes disponíveis. Neste caso, uma solução é ir guardando os nomes em uma lista, e no final você junta-os em uma string:

```
disponiveis = []
for nome, disponibilidade in horarios.items():
    if dia_da_semana in disponibilidade:
        inicio, fim = disponibilidade[dia_da_semana]
        if inicio <= horario <= fim:
            disponiveis.append(nome)

if disponiveis: # se encontrou alguém
    resposta = f'Disponíveis: {", ".join(disponiveis)}'
else: # não encontrou ninguém disponível
    resposta = 'Não há médicos disponíveis'

# usar a resposta aqui...
```

Criei a lista `disponiveis` contendo os nomes dos médicos encontrados. Depois, caso tenha algum, eu junto os nomes usando `join` (no exemplo acima usei `", "`, assim os nomes ficam separados por vírgula e espaço, mas você pode trocar para o que quiser). O resultado é uma string contendo os nomes de todos os médicos encontrados, que estará na variável `resposta`.

---

### Mais de um horário no mesmo dia

Se tiver mais de um horário no mesmo dia, aí muda um pouco. Nesse caso você precisa ter uma lista de tuplas (cada uma contendo o horário inicial e final). Algo assim:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

horarios = {
    'Carlos': {
        0: [(time(10, 0), time(12, 0)), (time(15, 0), time(16, 0))], # segunda, das 10h às 12h e das 15h às 16h 
        3: [(time(15, 0), time(16, 30))] # quinta, das 15h às 16:30
    },
    'Juliana': {
        0: [(time(10, 0), time(11, 30)), (time(15, 30), time(17, 0))], # segunda, das 10h às 11:30 e das 15:30 às 17h
        5: [(time(15, 0), time(16, 0))] # sexta, das 15h às 16h
    }
}

hoje = datetime.now()
dia_da_semana = hoje.weekday() # obter o dia da semana
horario = hoje.time() # pegar somente o horário

disponiveis = []
for nome, disponibilidade in horarios.items():
    if dia_da_semana in disponibilidade:
        # procurar na lista de horários
        for inicio, fim in disponibilidade[dia_da_semana]:
            if inicio <= horario <= fim:
                disponiveis.append(nome)
                break # encontrei horário nesse dia, posso interromper o loop
```

Comment: Consegui implementar. A minha dúvida é, caso um médico tenha 2 horários de atendimento no mesmo dia, isso iria funcionar?

Comment: @GabrielArruda Nesse caso muda um pouco. Atualizei a resposta com essa opção. Outra coisa: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.