# Mostrar dias da semana

Tags: python, data

Montei esse código para mostrar o dia da semana. Funciona, mas gostaria de saber se tem outro jeito com menos linhas/comandos que poderia usar. Ou um jeito mais 'limpo' por assim dizer.

```
import datetime

# Pega a data atual
dia = datetime.date.today().day
ano = datetime.date.today().year
mês = datetime.date.today().month
sem = ("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo")
ds = ("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta")

# Verifica que dia é hoje de acordo com o padrão de data em inglês ex:(2021/05/10)
num = datetime.date(ano, mês, dia).weekday()
p = (sem[num])

# De acordo com o número que 'p' tiver, é setado um dia da semana conforme o correspondente na lista 'ds'
# 'ds' é abreviação de Dias da Semana

# Verifica se o dia atual é dia útil, se não for é considerado 'fim de semana'
if p in ds:
    h = 'dia de semana'
else:
    h = 'fim de semana'

# Termina o código mostrando que dia é hoje
if h == 'dia de semana':
    print(f"Tenha uma boa {sem[num]} =D")
else:
    print(f"Tenha um bom {sem[num]} =D")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, não tem porque usar `datetime.date(ano, mês, dia)` se já esta usando `today()`

E para checar se é sábado ou domingo basta checar se o valor de weekday é maior que 4, se for menor que 5 é dia de semana, **não precisa** de `num in (5, 6)` (`tuple`) e nem de `num in {5, 6}` (`set`), **basta fazer `num < 5`**, já que como disse, os "finais" são 5 e 6, então você sabe que os dias "de semana" são de 0 a 4:

| Valor | Dia da semana |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Segunda |
| 1 | Terça |
| 2 | Quarta |
| 3 | Quinta |
| 4 | Sexta |
| 5 | Sábado |
| 6 | Domingo |

Usando a própria biblioteca que já esta usando em seu código:

```
from datetime import date

num = date.today().weekday()

sem = ("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo")

if num < 5:
    print(f"Tenha uma boa {sem[num]}-feira =D")
else:
    print(f"Tenha um bom {sem[num]} =D")
```

Comment: Caramba, como compliquei uma coisa tão simples de fazer kkkkk Agradeço a ajuda mano<3

Answer (score 4):

Tem bastante código não utilizado no seu algoritmo. Pelo que deu pra entender você quer dar um print em "Tenha uma boa XXX-Feira" ou "Tenha um bom Sábado/Domingo" mas você cria e não utiliza variáveis ou cria desnecessariamente.

Um exemplo de como poderia ser feito mais concisamente:

```py
from datetime import date

dia_semana = date.today().weekday()
nomes = ("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo")

if dia_semana in {5, 6}:
    print(f"Tenha um bom {nomes[dia_semana]} =D")
else:
    print(f"Tenha uma boa {nomes[dia_semana]} =D")
```

Como você não vai usar o objeto "hoje" criado com `date.today()`, não estou salvando em lugar nenhum pois só preciso qual é o dia da semana. Depois basta checar se é fim de semana e printar o nome correto.

Comment: Sou iniciante ainda em programação, por isso essa bagunça no meu código kk mas a sua resolução me ensinou mt, obrigado msm

Answer (score 3):

Sim, dá para ser mais simples.

Veja que você cria 3 vezes a data de hoje (`date.today()` é chamado 3 vezes), mas só precisaria chamar uma vez.

E depois você pega o dia, mês e ano da data de hoje e cria outro `date` com esses valores. Pra que? `date.today()` já retorna um `date` com exatamente esses valores, então é completamente desnecessário criar outra data com o mesmo dia, mês e ano.

E para formatar a data, basta usar `strftime`, usando o formato `"%A"` que corresponde ao dia da semana (veja mais sobre os formatos na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)). E para que esteja em português, você precisa setar o *locale*:

```
import locale
# setar locale para português
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')

from datetime import date

hoje = date.today() # data de hoje
if hoje.weekday() in (5, 6): # se o dia da semana é sábado ou domingo
    msg = 'um bom'
else:
    msg = 'uma boa'

print(f'Tenha {msg} {hoje.strftime("%A").title()} =D')
```

Como [`weekday()` retorna um número entre 0 e 6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) (sendo segunda=0, terça=1, ..., sábado=5, domingo=6), basta usar este valor para verificar se é fim de semana ou não. Depois você seta a mensagem de acordo, e use `strftime` para obter o nome do dia da semana. Também usei `title()` porque o dia da semana estava sendo retornado com letra minúscula.

E também criei outra variável para a parte que varia ("um bom"/"uma boa"), aí eu só imprimo a mensagem uma única vez (como parece ser sempre a mesma mensagem, mudando apenas esses detalhes, achei melhor assim).

---

Vale lembrar que para o código acima funcionar, o *locale* `pt_BR` deve estar instalado no sistema, conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385217/112052) (neste link também explica como verificar isso).

Mas caso o *locale* **não** esteja instalado (e você não quer/não sabe como instalar), aí o jeito é ter a lista de nomes mesmo:

```
from datetime import date

nomes = ["Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"]
ds = date.today().weekday()
if ds in (5, 6): # se o dia da semana é sábado ou domingo
    msg = 'um bom'
else:
    msg = 'uma boa'

print(f'Tenha {msg} {nomes[ds]} =D')
```

Comment: No fim minha resposta nem é mais necessária, a sua explica mais e acabamos com um código quase igual. hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio Eu só respondi pra falar sobre `strftime`, que a sua não tinha. Mas acho que não precisa apagar a sua não, até porque vc respondeu antes...

Comment: Por incrível q pareça, com o uso do locale, vc acaba de me ajudar em outro código que dava erro 'non-utf8' KKKKKK e ainda de quebra me ajudou com esse código, nem sei como agradeçer <33333

Answer (score 0):

Como responderam, você pode usar o weekday para buscar na tupla, sendo 0 segunda e 6 domingo.

```
    from datetime import date
    diadasemana = ('Segunda', 'terça', 'quarta', 'quinta', 'sexta', 'Sábado', 
    'Domingo')
    print("fim de semana" if (diadasemana[date.today().weekday()]) in (5, 6) else "dia 
    de semana")
    print(f'Tenha uma boa {diadasemana[date.today().weekday()]} :)!')
```

Comment: Gostei de como usou o if e else na mesma linha, ficou bem limpo de ver kkk vlw a ajuda mano =D

Comment: @Nerean O problema é que ele está verificando se `diadasemana[date.today().weekday()]` é 5 ou 6 (ou seja, se o **texto** é 5 ou 6, e nunca será, pois os textos são "Segunda", "Terça", etc). O certo é ver se o valor do `weekday` é 5 ou 6: `if date.today().weekday() in (5, 6)`. E também não haveria necessidade de chamar `date.today().weekday()` duas vezes, esse é um caso em que valeria a pena guardar o valor em uma variável (não vale a pena "economizar uma linha", sendo que pra isso vc teve que criar o mesmo objeto duas vezes)

Comment: Opa, testei ontem e hoje. Está correto :) Não estou buscando o texto, qdo coloco date.today().weekday dentro da chave, estou to indo na tupla diadasemana e pegando o índice dela pra validar meu "if". Abs

Comment: @CristianoMenezesSilva Eu sugiro que teste no sábado ou domingo então, e aí vai entender o que eu disse: vc verifica se `diadasemana[date.today().weekday()]` é 5 ou 6 (faça `print(diadasemana[date.today().weekday()])` e veja que ele imprime o texto, não o índice, então o `if` está vendo se o **texto** é 5 ou 6, portanto vai falhar no fim de semana). Na verdade nem precisa esperar pelo fim de semana, basta trocar `date.today()` por `date(2021, 5, 15)` (sábado) e veja o que acontece (vai dizer que é dia de semana, e não fim de semana).

Comment: Outro detalhe é que faltou ajustar o texto "uma boa" para "um bom" quando for sábado ou domingo (ou seja, ficará "Tenha um**a** bo**a** Domingo")

Comment: Show!! Muito obrigado pela resposta! :) abs